# Difference between RequestFocus and ReqeustFocusFromTouch?

Tags: java, android, focus

Want to know the actual difference between `RequestFocus` and `ReqeustFocusFromTouch`. When should each be used, how should each be used, and in which situations is each helpful?

Give some examples and explain them in detail.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From official doc

[**`requestFocus()`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#requestFocus())

- Call this to try to give focus to a specific `View` or to one of its descendants. A `View` will not actually take focus if it is not focusable (`isFocusable()` returns false),

[**`requestFocusFromTouch`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#requestFocusFromTouch())

- Call this to try to give focus to a specific view or to one of its descendants. This is a special variant of `requestFocus()` that will allow views that are not focusable in touch mode to request focus when they are touched.
- **Returns**
  `boolean`
  Whether this view or one of its descendants actually took focus.